# BigQuery not showing any dataset for a linked Firebase Analytics Event logs

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I linked my account to Big Query but Firebase Analytics events are not getting loaded into BigQuery automatically.

"No dataset found" warning is shown.

My work progress was attached below please find.

I have getting firebase Analytics event log in debugView console. for your reference [image]

Link Big Query with my application [image]

"No dataset found in this project" warning is shown in Big Query Web UI[image]

i have added the FireBase event log code in my application button onClick.[image]

Not sure what other steps i need to be get the FireBase Analytics Event logs in Big Query Dataset. Please guide me. Thanks