# BIgQuery is showing dataset for a linked Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-bigquery, analytics

I linked my account to Big Query but Firebase Analytics events are not getting loaded into BigQuery automatically.

"No dataset found" warning is shown.

I've referred  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429444/bigquery-not-showing-any-dataset-for-a-linked-firebase-analytics-event-logs) too,
me too having the same issue but I couldn't find any solution, please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/3ikRSRQXJVc

Comment: @  Frank van Puffelen, i am also referred this link. but no answer thr.

Comment: @Aravindh, if you find this issue solution pls update hear. thx

Comment: @Aravindh: both firebase-talk and Stack Overflow are community support forums, so there is no guarantee anyone will answer. But it is a common courtesy to indicate when you cross-post, to reduce the risk of multiple people spending time on the same question unknowingly. If you want a guaranteed response, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.